# Is there a simple way to sync android app between devices?

Tags: android, sql, synchronization

I have a list I keep in SQL dB and would like to sync it with at least 2 android devices.

I tried reading into sync adapter and it seems very complicated and too much for syncing a list.

Is this my only option or there is a simpler option?
The problem is I am short in time. So I wouldn't like to start implementing a general and complicated solution when I can implement something more specific and simple. This app is for myself only so I'd like to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sync a list you can create a web service (server side). Identify the business logic e.g. say you want to keep the union of two lists.

You can have sync implemented from server side using push notification or may be say once a day when the app comes in foreground. You can also have a alarm based syncing where you can schedule this process.

Then you may not need whole adapter stuff. You can just consume this service and sync your data. Just decide for yourself.